# GPUs not being utilized despite mirrored strategy tensor flow

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I'm trying to analyze an EMG dataset in tensor flow using a CNN. Each input data is a 2D array with the rows being each individual emg recording channel and the columns containing the emg recording w respect to time. This is the model:

```
def conv_model():
  visible = Input(shape = (len(training_input[0]), len(training_input[0][0]), 1))

  conv = Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding = 'same')(visible)
  pooling = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2, padding='valid')(conv)

  conv2 = Conv2D(filters=124, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding = 'same')(pooling)
  pooling2 =  MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2, padding='valid')(conv2)

  conv3 = Conv2D(filters=248, kernel_size=(2,2), activation='relu', padding = 'same')(pooling2)
  pooling3 =  MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2, padding='valid')(conv3)

  flatten = Flatten()(pooling3)
  dropout = Dropout(0.5)(flatten)

  hidden = Dense(units=80, activation = 'relu')(dropout)
  hidden_2 = Dense(units=100, activation = 'relu')(hidden)
  hidden_3 = Dense(units=60, activation = 'relu')(hidden_2)

  output = Dense(units=len(movement_list), activation = 'softmax')(hidden_3)

  model = Model(inputs=visible, outputs=output)
  return model
```

Here I define an alternate optimizer and a dataset class and use tensor flow's Mirrored Strategy to utilize GPUs

```
class SwitchOptimizer(Callback):
    def __init__(self, optimizer1, optimizer2, switch_epoch):
        super().__init__()
        self.optimizer1 = optimizer1
        self.optimizer2 = optimizer2
        self.switch_epoch = switch_epoch

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        if epoch == self.switch_epoch:
            self.model.optimizer = self.optimizer2

class EMGDataset(tf.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, x_data, y_data, batch_size):
        super(EMGDataset).__init__()
        self.x_data = x_data
        self.y_data = y_data
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def _generator(self):
        for x_window, y in zip(self.x_data, self.y_data):
            yield x_window, y

    def __iter__(self):
        return self._generator()

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.x_data)

    def get_tensor_slices(self):
        return tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((self.x_data, self.y_data))

    def _inputs(self):
        return tf.TensorSpec(shape=(len(training_input[0]), len(training_input[0][0])), dtype=tf.float32)

    def element_spec(self):
        return (
            tf.TensorSpec(shape=(len(training_input[0]), len(training_input[0][0])), dtype=tf.float32),
            tf.TensorSpec(shape=(len(movement_list),), dtype=tf.float32),
        )

    def get_distributed_dataset(self, strategy):
        dataset = self.get_tensor_slices()
        dataset = dataset.shuffle(len(self))
        dataset = dataset.batch(self.batch_size)
        dataset = dataset.repeat()
        dataset = strategy.experimental_distribute_dataset(dataset)
        return dataset
        
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()

with strategy.scope():
    model = conv_model()
    #generating compiler
    op = SwitchOptimizer(tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), keras.optimizers.RMSprop(), 12)
    model.compile(
        optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(),
        loss=keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
        metrics=[keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()],
    )
    
    model.summary()
    
    batch_size = 800
    train_dataset = EMGDataset(np.array(training_input), np.array(training_output), batch_size).get_distributed_dataset(strategy)
    val_dataset = EMGDataset(np.array(testing_input), np.array(testing_output), batch_size).get_distributed_dataset(strategy)

    history = model.fit(
        train_dataset,
        steps_per_epoch=len(training_input)//batch_size,
        epochs=20,
        callbacks=[op],
        validation_data=val_dataset,
        validation_steps=len(testing_input)//batch_size,
    )
```

When I run this code on a high performance computing laboratory, the session times out due to low gpu usage: **Please check this job to save GPU resources, jobs with very low GPU usages for more than 2 hours will be killed.** This only happens if the GPU is not utilized at all. I cannot figure out what is causing this.

Additional information: I'm running this using 3 cpus and 2 gpus with tensorflow-rocm using AMD gpus

Imports:

```
import numpy as np
import os

from scipy import signal
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Input, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import Callback

import scipy.io as sio
import tensorflow as tf

config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config)
tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.set_session(sess)
```

Comment: You don't need to GPUs for this model, its too small. Make sure that you do not do premature optimization.

Comment: I do since I'm intaking gigabytes of data. Around 10gbs

Comment: No, that is not how it works, if dataset is too large you would be IO bound, not compute bound. More GPUs increase computation which is not your botleneck.